# C# - unable to terminate Process with CreateNoWindow set to true

Tags: c#, process, cmd

I'm trying to interact with handbrakes's cli and I'm having problems terminating it's process when needed.

Process is started like so

```
        string command = "/c \"C:\\Program Files\\Handbrake\\HandBrakeCLI.exe\" -i " + disk.Info.Name + " -o " + disk.Info.VolumeLabel + ".mkv -t " + titleNum + " -e x264 -q 18.0 -f mkv -4 --decomb --loose-anamorphic --modulus 2 -m --x264-preset medium --h264-profile high --h264-level 4.1";

        _p = new Process();
        _p.StartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo("cmd.exe", command)
        {
            UseShellExecute = false,
            CreateNoWindow = true,
            RedirectStandardError = true,
            RedirectStandardOutput = true
        };

        _p.OutputDataReceived += OutputCallback;
        _p.ErrorDataReceived += OutputCallback;

        _p.Start();

        _p.BeginErrorReadLine();
        _p.BeginOutputReadLine();

        _p.WaitForExit();
```

I have tried terminating it with `_p.Kill()`, `_p.Close()`, `_p.Dispose()` and `_p.CloseMainWindow()`. The last one works but only when `CreateNoWindow = false`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you are starting the shell and telling it to start Handbrake; `_p` refers to the shell process. Killing it obviously has no effect on Handbrake.

You should start Handbrake directly instead:

```
string command = " -i " + disk.Info.Name + " -o " + disk.Info.VolumeLabel + ".mkv -t " + titleNum + " -e x264 -q 18.0 -f mkv -4 --decomb --loose-anamorphic --modulus 2 -m --x264-preset medium --h264-profile high --h264-level 4.1";

_p = new Process();
_p.StartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo("C:\\Program Files\\Handbrake\\HandBrakeCLI.exe\", command)
{
    UseShellExecute = false,
    CreateNoWindow = true,
    RedirectStandardError = true,
    RedirectStandardOutput = true
};
```

Comment: Works perfect, not quite sure why I was doing it the other way